# Change magento folder screwed up the style

Tags: magento

I installed a magento website in my root folder "/". Everything was working fine until I moved all the contents of magento in a subfolder in the domain. So instead of having the magento in the root folder, it is now under a subfolder.

The problem is, the design is screwed up. It is not showing the css and images for the default theme.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the base url setting.

It's very likely your admin panel stopped working as well, so look into the DB table `core_config_data`. Look for the paths `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` and update the corresponding `value` fields to include the new folder.

**Dont't forget to put a trailing slash to the new urls**